# Will the log of wood sink in the water?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light

Imagine the water in a river is flowing with speed very close to the speed of light. There is a log of wood tied to any object outside the river so that it doesn't go ahead with water and is at rest with respect to the ground.
Now, let I also start moving with speed same as that of water and in the same direction as that of water. So, now the log of wood is moving with respect to me with the same speed in the opposite direction.
According to special theory of relativity, it's mass will increase and length will be contracted as compared to when it was at rest with respect to me. So, as a result, its density should increase. However, the water is at rest in my frame of reference. So its density will be only 1000kg/m^3. So, the wooden log should sink into the water.
But how it is possible that it is outside the water in one frame of reference and inside the water for another frame of reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplee%27s_paradox

Comment: @Ben_Crowell thanks for this reference.

Answer (score -2):

No the log won't sink, since what makes the log sink to the bottom of the river is gravity, and when u attain such velocity the effect of gravity is negligible and whatever the density of tow bodies the log wont sink

Comment: This answer is completely unphysical, as well as the question contains several mistakes.